# On continuous functions

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ be continuous and such that $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)=0$. Show that the set $\{x \in (0,1] : f(x)=0 \}$ has a minimum.

So I though because the function is continuous, it is bounded. Since it is bounded it must have a inf and a sup. Since a inf exists in a bounded set I could achrimedian proof it is the minimum. But my professor told me that since the set he wants a minimum in is unbounded my logic wont work. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The set is closed in $[0,1].$

Comment: Not in the set im looking for a minimum in?

Answer (score 1):

The point of the exercise is this:

The set $\{x \in (0,1] : f(x)=0 \}$ obviously has an infimum, because it is non-empty and bounded below. But is this infimum necessarily a minimum? That is, does the infimum itself belong to the set? This is what you have to prove.

It seems to me that you missed this. It also seems that you must have misunderstood your professor -- what he allegedly said makes no sense to me..

(Also, I presume you mean "archimedean proof". But what do you mean by this?)

Answer (score 1):

Continuity and $f(0)<0$ implies that there exists a small $\epsilon>0$ such that if $0\leq x<\epsilon$, $f(x) < 0$. Then, the zeros of $f$ are contained in the compact set $[\epsilon,1]$. Now let $x_0 = \inf_{[\epsilon,1]}\left\{ x : f(x) = 0 \right\}$. If this is a finite set, then we are done. If not, consider a sequence from the set converging to $x_0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $f(x_0)=0$ and certainly $x_0\in[\epsilon,1]$ due to compactness. Hence $x_0$ is the desired minimum.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $:$ $\{x \in (0,1] : f(x) = 0 \} = f^{-1} (0).$ Since $f$ is continuous so $f^{-1} (0)$ is a closed subspace of $[0,1]$ (Since $\{0 \}$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R$). Since $[0,1]$ is a closed subspace of $\Bbb R$ with usual topology so $f^{-1} (0)$ is a closed subspace of $\Bbb R$ with usual topology.

Comment: Inverse image of $\{0 \}$ under $f$ is a closed subspace of $[0,1]$ since $\{0 \}$ is a closed subspace of $\Bbb R$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Very confused we havnt used much topology in this class so I am not very familiar with it.

Comment: Closed subspace of $[0,1]$ is of the form $A \cap [0,1]$ where $A$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R.$ Hence the subsets which are closed in $[0,1]$ must also be closed in $\Bbb R$ since intersection of two closed subsets of $\Bbb R$ is also a closed subset of $\Bbb R.$

Comment: Do you know @JJ Burt that every closed subset of $\Bbb R$ attains it's infimum?

Comment: that does sound familiar so becuase its a subset?

Comment: So $f^{-1} (0)$ is a closed subset of $\Bbb R.$ So it attains it's infimum or in other words the set $\{x \in (0,1] : f(x) = 0 \}$ has a minimum and you are through. Do you know what is the minimum of a set?